# Menu/Button images lost after suspend

Tags: suspend, 21.04

After I suspended my PC, I don't see any menu button/images. Is there any solution? I couldn't find anything on the forum.

Graphic card: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] / GeForce GTX 850M/PCIe/SSE2

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Please edit the question and (1) **describe** the problem in context alongside the screenshots and (2) post the hardware specifications particularly the graphics and if applicable which driver version you're using.

Comment: Yes, please check my ss, it is the problem exactly what you will see. I wrote my graphics.

Comment: And have you installed Nvidia graphics? Which version? You can easily check at Nvidia X Server Settings.

Comment: Yes, I installed it. It is :  460.91.03

Comment: Nvidia now recommends 470. It should be available at Additional Drivers.

Comment: Okay. But I have to use GPU for my work. And I installed Cuda Cudnn versions that are compatible with Nvidia 460.
 But THANK YOU.

Comment: If so, avoid suspending and prefer shutdown/reboot.

Comment: Ok.  The Only solution is to shut down. On Win OS, there is no problem like that. Thank you.